# Minimizing a function with a constant $l > 0$

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I'm **VERY** new to Mathematica and would like some help with minimizing a function.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\left(l^4+x^4\right)^2}{l^4 x^2}}$$

I want to find which $x-value$ (probably depending on $l$) yields the lowest function value, where $l > x > 0$.

Mathematica input for function:

```
1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)]
```

---

#### What I tried:

```
Minimize[1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)], {x}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)], {x, 0, l}], {l, 1, 10}]
```

Output:

> [image: Output]

Comment: Please post the code you already tried

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `Plot[1/2 Sqrt[(x (l + x)^2)/l] /. l -> 1, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: The output you're getting seems the right answer. What do you expect?

Comment: @belisarius I encountered something weird just now. Trying the two different roots I got from output: I try setting $l=1$ and then solve the roots numerically, from one I get 0.877... and the other I get -0.759...

However, using plot and zooming in, I can see it's probably supposed to be +0.759... What's the matter here?

Manipulate[
 Plot[1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)], {x, 0.7, 0.9}], {l, 1, 1}]

Comment: @B.Lee plot instead from -0.9 to 0.9, you will see that your expression is symmetric under `x->-x`.  So if there's a minimum at +0.759 there is also one at -0.759.  You might also try `Solve[D[1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)], x] == 0, x]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output looks fine to me.  It is, however, relatively complicated.  Consider the following simpler example

```
Minimize[x (x - c), x]
(* Out: {-c^2/4, {x -> c/2}} *)
```

Thus, there is a minimum value of $y=-c^2/4$ at $x=c/2$, as expected.  Now, let's complicate things slightly.

```
Minimize[c x (x - c), x]
```

[image]

This is a *piecewise* expression, which is necessary since the result depends crucially on whether $c$ is positive, negative, or zero.  Your problem has generated a piecewise expression for the same reason.  You've also got a further complication since Mathematica has returned `Root` expressions.  This is is often *necessary*.  For example, the solutions of $x^5-x-1=0$ cannot be easily expressed in terms of radicals.  That explains the following cryptic output:

```
Solve[x^5 - x - 1 == 0, x, Reals]
(* Out: {x -> Root[-1 - #1 + #1^5 &, 1]}} *)
```

Thus, the one real solution is the first root of $-1-x+x^5$.  Doesn't seem very useful, but you can evaluate this numerically.

```
N[%]
(* Out: {{x -> 1.1673}} *)
```

Now, your solution is expressed in terms of the roots of a fourth degree polynomial, and we *can* get an alternative formulation which *might* be more to your liking.  I'm not sure.  Here goes, though:

```
minInfo = Minimize[1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)], {x}] //. 
  r_Root :> Simplify[ToRadicals[r]]
```

[image]

A bit better, I guess.  It's much better, if you plug in a specific value:

```
minInfo /. l -> 3
(* Out: {-2 3^(1/4), {x -> 3^(3/4)}} *)
```

I emphasize that you could have plugged numbers in anyway, as Beli showed in his answer.

Comment: WOW! You are.. You are the best! You have no idea how long it's taken me to understand this. I would give you +3 if I could!

Comment: @B.Lee An accept is ample and you're welcome.  Maybe Beli could bounty it, as he has 64K these days. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure You've got my +1. My kids already took control of their inheritance.

Answer (score 7):

```
Manipulate[
 p = {x, s@x} /. Last@Minimize[{s@x, l > x > 0}, {x}];
 Plot[s@x, {x, 0, l}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point@p}, PlotLabel -> p], {l, 1, 10},
 Initialization :> {s@x_ := 1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Since you give the constraint l > x > 0, you should make use of that constraint

```
f[x_] = 1/2 Sqrt[(l^4 + x^4)^2/(l^4 x^2)];

min = FullSimplify[
  Minimize[{f[x], l > x > 0}, x], l > x > 0]
```

[image]

```
min[[1]] == Simplify[f[x /. min[[2]]], l > 0]
```

> True

```
f'[x] /. min[[2]]
```

> 0

```
Simplify[(f''[x] /. min[[2]]) > 0, l > 0]
```

> True

Comment: Thank you. I discovered the equation you got, and figured it didn't print that one out from the start because I hadn't specified the constraints. This helped me see how to apply constraints.

Answer (score 2):

here is another way to approach the problem...

[image]

Comment: Please post code, not images whenever possible. Thanks a lot!