# Reduce function response to a single number

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
m = 7;
x[t_] = 6 t^4 + t^2;
y[t_] = 3 ArcTan[t] - 1;
z[t_] = 2 t^3 + 1;
F = 140;
eqn = x''[t] m + y''[t] m + z''[t] m;
mySol1 = Reduce[eqn > F && t > 0, t];


t > Root[-3 + #1 + 6 #1^2 + 4 #1^3 + 21 #1^4 + 2 #1^5 + 12 #1^6 &, 2]
```

How can I get an answer one number?

Comment: See the second example in the documentation for `Root`.  If that does not address your question, please clarify.

Comment: Try `N` for a numeric result.

Comment: See this [recent answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69349/245) by Mark McClure. It gives some relevant tricks you could use.